# LAMP Server with multiple PHP Versions

Tags: 13.10, apache2, php, lamp

I am looking for a way to install multiple versions of PHP on my notebook to work on different projects that require different versions of PHP.

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and installed apache2, php5, mysql etc from the repository. I have now PHP 5.5 installed, and I would like to have also PHP 5.3 for some projects that don't work well with PHP 5.5.

So I need a way to have multiple versions of PHP installed on my system and switch between them depending on the project I'm working on, or better configure the vhost to use the chosen version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you compile both Apache and PHP from source code instead of installing via aptitude. This may be a tedious process for you if you're a beginner. You also need to have Apache listen to port other than 80 if you want your two PHPs requests at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the php version in the file named .htaccess (one htaccess for each website with the php version of your choice)
http://sourcelibrary.org/2011/04/13/linux-enabling-use-of-apaches-htaccess-files/

Comment: I'm not asking for setting php version for virtual hosts. I'm asking how to **install** multiple php versions side by side, so that I can switch between them for different projects.